# Subtract previous row value from the current row value in a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas column with the name 'values' containing respective values `10 15 36 95 99`. I want to subtract the each value from the next value so that I get the following format: `10 5 21 59 4`

I've tried to solve this using a for loop that loops over all the data-frame but this method was time consuming.

```py
for i in range(1,length_colulmn):
    df['value'].iloc[i] = df['value'].iloc[i]-df['value'].iloc[i-1]
```

Is there a straightforward method the dataframe functions to solve this problem quickly? 
The output we desire is the following:

```
['input']                                       
11
15
22
27
36
69
77

['output']                                        
11
4
7
5
9
33
8
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.diff` with `fillna`:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([11,15,22,27,36,69,77])
s.diff().fillna(s)
```

Output:

```
0    11.0
1     4.0
2     7.0
3     5.0
4     9.0
5    33.0
6     8.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @pentanol `s.diff().fillna(0)` is what you want

Answer (score 5):

You can use the pythonic `shift` function. see how I did it. Let me know if it works.

Code here:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'input': [11, 15, 22, 27, 36, 69, 77]})

df['output']=df['input'] -df['input'].shift(1)

df
#df['output'].dropna()
```

Explanation:

1. create dataframe
2. create a column output such that the next row minus the current row
3. print dataframe

Result:

```
    input   output
0   11  NaN
1   15  4.0
2   22  7.0
3   27  5.0
4   36  9.0
5   69  33.0
6   77  8.0
```

you can remove `NaN` with `dropna()`.

Comment: In my case I needed the NaN value, so this solution worked for me thanks.

Comment: May i ask how could I apply your code to multiple columns?

Comment: it can be done, but your question is not very clear. so you want to subtract current column from multiple columns? Just reference those columns in the shift. If you can start a new question and link it up here, I will go and have a look